# Clang remove -internal-externc-isystem from include serach path

Tags: clang++, llvm-clang, webassembly

I am trying to build a c++ CMAKE webassembly project using latest emscripten. During the build i notice that clang is including directories which SHOULD NOT be included i.e. from the compile command i see those flags:

```
-internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-internal-externc-isystem /include 
-internal-externc-isystem /usr/include
```

from here
https://gist.github.com/masuidrive/5231110

-internal-externc-isystem

> Add directory to the internal system include search path with implicit
>   extern "C" semantics; these are assumed to not be user-provided and
>   are used to model system and standard headers' paths.

Since those directories should not be in my include search path and indeed they are the reason for an error, my question is, is there a CMAKE directive that tells clang to strip/remove any "internal-externc-isystem" or all of them. Or  maybe a clang flag or a way to exclude them from the include path. Bottom line i do not what them on my include search path.

```
emscripten version  (deaa7e4bfd79246f02f785c8f2174d1e74ab6c00) 
clang  version 10.0.0 (/b/s/w/ir/cache/git/chromium.googlesource.com-external-github.com-llvm-llvm--project 06cfcdcca7de9c88a1e885eff0d0c4c07090ad48)
```

Comment: Are you using the emcmake wrapper/helper?

Comment: yes I am using emcmake